# .ASPXAUTH cookie dissappears automatically

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, cookies

I have a problem with .ASPXAUTH cookie. When login action i create forms authentication

```
 FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Araclar.config.Username , false);
```

and i redirect web page to index. For first time cookie works but suddenly .ASPXAUTH cookie disappears. And when i click other links web site redirect me to login because there is no .ASPXAUTH

i use custom authorize validation and its like that

```
public class LoginCheck : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (Araclar.config == null)
        {
            var config =
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Config>(
                    System.IO.File.ReadAllText(httpContext.Server.MapPath("~/app_data/config.json")));
            Araclar.config = config;
        }

        return Araclar.config.Username ==  httpContext.User.Identity.Name;

    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: None of the code you have posted pertains to the `.ASPXAUTH` cookie. Could you please post the details/code pertaining to why you think the cookie is disappearing? If the user's login session is still active, you should be getting `true` for `httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` (which you can use as a guard to make sure the rest of your code isn't run for unauthenticated users).

Comment: when i login for the first time i see the cookie on the chrome's cookie but in 10 seconds cookie deleting it self or some code deleting it but i couldnt find. [Authorize] attribute works nice without error but on the admin panel which i use custom authorize , i face with this problem.

Comment: @NightOwl888 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fjFy_xnRGVE&feature=youtu.be i send video